# To show the cells where the values have changed and also exhibit previous values existing in the changed cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, to log the changes in a sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim val
    Dim dtmTime As Date
    Dim Rw As Long
    Dim x As String

    Sheets("Shipment").Select

    If Intersect(Target, Range("D3:D200,K3:K200")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    dtmTime = Now()
    val = Target.Value
    strAddress = Target.Address
    x = Cells(2, Target.Column).Value

    Rw = Sheets("Log Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
   With Sheets("Log Sheet")
      .Cells(Rw, 1) = strAddress
      .Cells(Rw, 2) = val
      .Cells(Rw, 3) = dtmTime
      .Cells(Rw, 4) = x
   End With
End Sub
```

This only shows me the new value, i also want to see the old value of the cell. That is where i need help. If anyone could tell me how i can incorporate a column to show the old values of the changed cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Copy Column D and Paste it in Column DD

Then Copy below Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim val
    Dim dtmTime As Date
    Dim Rw As Long
    Dim x As String

    Sheets("Shipment").Select

   If Intersect(Target, Range("D3:D200,K3:K200")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    dtmTime = Now()
    val = Target.Value
    Old_val = Sheets("Shipment").Range("DD" & Target.Row)
    strAddress = Target.Address
    x = Cells(2, Target.Column).Value

    Rw = Sheets("Log Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Sheets("Log Sheet")
       .Cells(Rw, 1) = strAddress
       .Cells(Rw, 2) = val
       .Cells(Rw, 3) = Old_val
       .Cells(Rw, 4) = dtmTime()
       .Cells(Rw, 5) = x
    End With
    Sheets("Shipment").Range("DD" & Target.Row) = Target.Value
End Sub
```

[image]

Hope this is what you wanted. :)

Comment: so for example if cell G6 has value changed from "1" to "2" .
currently, it shows g6 in column 1 and column 2 shows 2, i want a third column which shows the old value (in this case ,"1"). Thank you

Comment: From my knowledge, Only way to do that is to assign changed value to different cell, then save the value from different cell whenever worksheet changes instead. So very first value before change will be "" then so on...

Comment: how can i incorporate it to this code ? or is that not possible?
sorry i am not the best at vba hence the question. thank you :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. And Sheet does not have to be unused sheet. It can be any sheet. The range must be unused cell. Otherwise, the value will be all mixed up

Comment: this does not seem to be working for me. I have no idea why. should they both be the same?

Comment: No. It shouldn't be.It is suppose to write current value to Column2 and old value to Column 3. Is there other macro that are running?    Let's try change both of those Sheet(*Unused sheet*).Range(*Unused range*) to Sheets("Shipment").Range("ZZ1"). Let me know what it does

Comment: Still no luck, it returns blank for the previous value. I think i might have not explained very well. The "Shipments" Sheet has a lot of orders. The column D in the shipments sheet shows like a status (Live or Posted or waiting). Currently the log sheet shows that the status has been changed to for example "posted", but I want  a column next to it showing the "old status". So, if i change a status from live to posted, i want two columns one which says posted( i already have that), another one showing the old value in this case " live".

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do with this project? Are you trying to log what time it was Live or Posted or waiting? I would love to help. It's just really hard to understand without knowing what worksheet looks like :p

Comment: haha ermmm.. i want to be able to sort it in terms of status. so i will have 100 of shipments but only few of them change, so i want to be able to see which ones changed and from what. if that makes sense! :)

Comment: I am sorry for late response. That does make sense. I understand what you are trying to do. Now my next question is are you going to be looking through log sheet to see the changes? or will the changes will be displayed somewhere else using datas from log sheets?

Comment: its fine! sorry for the late reply.  I will be mainly using this log sheet to view changes but i don't mind adding a new sheet if it makes things easier.

Comment: I've updated the post. Let me know for further questions

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You smashed it. exactly what i needed. Thank a ton!

Answer (score 0):

A fully complete solution will involve creating a duplicate of your "Shipment" worksheet to use a baseline for previous values. Here's how to set it up:

1. Create a copy of your "Shipment" worksheet and rename it to "Shipment-OldValues". (Optionally you can make this sheet hidden to your users.)
2. Make sure to delete any VBA code directly associated with this duplicate sheet. (You don't want a `Worksheet_Change` event firing for this one.)
3. In the `Worksheet_Change` event code of the "Shipment" worksheet, when you determine the target cell that has changed, you can easily grab the previous value from the "Shipment-OldValues" worksheet.
4. Log the value change in your "Log Sheet" and add another column to note the previous value of that cell.
5. Make sure to store the NEW value of the changed cell in the "Shipment-OldValues" worksheet for the next change.
6. If you need to work backwards over several edits for the same cell, all the previous values will be noted in your "Log Sheet" and you'll be able to track it back as far as your log goes.

My own recommendation is to keep the "Shipment-OldValues" worksheet hidden, as it will cause less confusion to any user.

Comment: I have tried adding another sheet and it does indeed work but i prefer not to add another sheet even if it was hidden just to avoid any confusion for fellow users. Thank you for your solution tho! i appreciate it!